# Enabling selectable mode dynamically

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When I configure fullCalendar with the "selectable: true" initialization parameter, the selectability functionality is great, but I need to enable/disable this functionality dynamically! That is, the calendar stars off with no selectability, then the user clicks a button and I turn it on, clicks another button, and I turn it off again.

I checked out the "Height" parameter API page (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/height/) and it shows that I can set this parameter dynamically, but when I adapt the code to the "selectable" parameter, it does nothing:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar("option", "selectable", true);
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

-Brian

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but there seems to be a "render" method, maybe that renders the complete state including whether you can select or not. Try:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar("option", "selectable", true)
              .fullCalendar("render");
```

If that doesn't work, you could try re-creating your calendar, by destroying it first:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy')
              .fullCalendar({selectable: false, your: 'other', options: 'here'});
```

Comment: The alternative is the only thing that works (destroying and recreating).

Answer (score 0):

> Since version 2.9.0, it is possible to dynamically set options after
>   initalization. These option modifications will be applied to all
>   views. It is not currently possible to set View-Specific Options in
>   this manner.
>
> You can dynamically set a single option:
>
> ```
> $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'locale', 'fr');
> ```
>
> Or if you would like to set multiple options at once, limiting the
>   calendar to at most one repaint, pass in an option hash:
>
> ```
> $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', {
>   locale: 'fr',
>   isRTL: true
> });
> ```
>
> https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/dynamic-options